# Passing data from child component to parent and then to another child not working on page load but works after minor potentially unrelated change

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am new to Vuejs and come across this bug which I have no idea what I have done wrong. I am not receiving any console errors. It doesn't work on initial page load but it seems to work after I comment something out (or make a minor change). It will still then continue to work if I reverse the changes I just made and put it back to the original code. But once again on a fresh page load it won't work.

The issue: I am making a to do list and on page load when I add new tasks through the input field, the list does not appear on the page like it should be. I also console log the data array for this and it shows it is getting added to the array but is not getting rendered to the page. No console errors. In my code I will comment out some other data property (there are 2 additional ones below todosList in the TodoList.vue file that are currently not being used yet) and save and then the tasks will automatically appear on the page. So I think oh ok that might be the issue so with this new minor change I decide to refresh the page to see if it works as expected. Nope it doesn't so I then uncomment out what I previously commented out and save and the list appears again. But once again if I refresh the page it doesn't work. It only seems to be if I make a change inside the data function in the TodoList.vue file.

Additional info: The data is stored in the parent `todos[]` (App.vue), updated/pushed to array in a child (TodoCreate.vue) and sent back to the parent using `$emit`. This data is then sent through to another child (TodoList.vue) using `props` so that it can be rendered on the page.

Wondering if there is something that is not quite right in my code which is causing this to bug out like that. I will include everything in case it is something that looks unrelated to me but could be causing it.

Here is also a link to a code sandbox where the issue can be replicated by following the instructions on the page https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-new-todo-not-working-properly-jwwex?file=/src/components/TodoList.vue

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div :class="currentMode">
    <the-header @modeToggled="updateMode($event)"></the-header>
    <main>
      <todo-create @addedTodos="updateTodos"></todo-create>
      <todo-list :todos="todos"></todo-list>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';
import TodoCreate from './components/TodoCreate.vue';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    TodoCreate,
    TodoList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentMode: {
        dark_mode: true,
        light_mode: false
      },
      todos: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateMode(mode) {
      this.currentMode = mode;
    },
    updateTodos(data) {
      this.todos = data;
      console.log(this.todos);
    },
    toggleCompleted() {

    }
  },
  // provide() {
  //   return {
  //     todos: this.todos,
  //   };
  // }
}
</script>
```

**TheHeader.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>To-do App</h1>
    <div>
        <label for="toggle-mode" aria-label="Toggle light and dark mode"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-mode" @change="toggleMode">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    emits: ['modeToggled'],
    data() {
        return {
        toggleState: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleMode() {
            this.toggleState = !this.toggleState;
            this.$emit('modeToggled', this.modeClasses);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        modeClasses() {
            return {
                dark_mode: !this.toggleState,
                light_mode: this.toggleState
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**TodoCreate.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="newtodo" class="sr-only">Create new to do</label>
        <input type="text" id="newtodo" placeholder="Create a new todo..." v-model="todoval" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo" >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    emits: ['addedTodos'],
    data() {
        return {
            todoval: '',
            taskNumber: 0,
            todos: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addTodo() {
            const val = this.todoval;
            const taskNumber = this.taskNumber;
            this.todos.push({ taskID: taskNumber, value: val, complete : 'not-completed'});
            this.todoval = '';
            this.taskNumber++;
            console.log(this.todos);
            this.$emit('addedTodos', this.todos);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

**TodoList.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul class="todo-items" :class="filterClass">
        <li class="drop-zone" v-for="(listItem, index) in todosList" :class="listItem.complete" :key="listItem.taskID" 
        @drop='onDrop($event, index)' 
        @dragover.prevent
        @dragenter.prevent>
        <div class="drag-el" draggable="true"
            @dragstart='startDrag($event, index)'>
            <label :for="'checkbox-'+index" :aria-label="'Mark task ' + listItem.value + ' as completed'"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" :id="'checkbox-'+index" @change="toggleCompleted(index, listItem.value, listItem.complete, listItem.taskID)">
            <input type="text" disabled :value="listItem.value">
            <img src="../assets/icon-cross.svg" @click="removeTask(index)">
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        todos: Object,
        filterClass: String
    },
    // inject: ['todos'],
    data() {
        return {
            todosList: this.todos,
            // completedTodos: [],
            // activeTodos: [],
        };
    },
    // watch: {
    //     todosList(data) {
    //         data.filter(function(todo) {
    //             if(todo.completed == 'completed') {
    //                 completedTodos.push(todos);
    //             }
    //         });
    //     } 
    // },
    methods: {
        startDrag: (evt, item) => {
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'
            evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
            evt.dataTransfer.setData('itemID', item)
        },
        onDrop (evt, list) {
            const itemID = evt.dataTransfer.getData('itemID');
            const movedData = this.todosList[itemID];
            this.todosList.splice(itemID,1);
            this.todosList.splice(list,0, movedData);
        },
        toggleCompleted() {
            // still need to write this method
        },
        removeTask() {
            // still need to write this method
        }
    }
}
</script>
```